# What is the best approach to train a pytorch model over large dataset stored in a database?

Tags: python, sqlite, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a large dataset, and for convenience, I put it in an sqlite database. It has about 270k rows, each row has 10_000 bp long DNA sequence. It's impossible to load the entire dataset at once, let alone train a model (yeah, I tried, and my laptop's GPU ain't running / making any noise).

So currently I am running a loop. In each iteration, I am selecting paged data using offset and limit (say 500 sequences at a time) from the database, and training on the model on those 500 sequences with, say, 10 epochs.

The relevant part of my code:

```py
my_offset = 0
my_limit = 500
my_batch_size = 100

some_model = MyModel()

db_page_number = 0

# pagination
while db_page_number < 100:
  db_page_number += 1
  my_offset += my_limit

  query = f"SELECT sequences, classification FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT {my_limit} OFFSET {my_offset}"
  paged_data = pd.read_sql_query(query)
  
  x, y = get_x_y_from(paged_data)
  train_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x, y)
  train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=my_batch_size)
  for epoch in range(0, 10):
    # ... typical pytorch code...
    for data in train_loader:
      x1, y1 = data
      predicted_outputs = self.pytorch_model(x1)  # predict output from the model
      train_loss = self.loss_function(predicted_outputs, y1)  # calculate loss for the predicted output
      train_loss.backward()  # back propagate the loss
      optimizer.step()  # adjust params based on the calculated gradients
      # ... typical pytorch code...
```

Here, I am doing the pagination manually (the outer most while loop). I managed to run my code, but I wonder what is the best practice? Maybe using pandas, or some other library for for pagination part? I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to have a "pagination_control" table from which the limit and offset can be obtained.

So two primary columns (e.g. `p_limit` and `p_offset`).

This could then facilitate a flexible approach in that the limits and offset could be altered to suit. However, to facilitate the next block/group/set of rows. After a selection has been extracted an update of the "paginataion_control" table could then ready it for the next block/group/set of sequences by adding the limit to the offset.

**Demo**

You may wish to consider the following demo:-

```
/* Cleanup demo environment just in case */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pagination_control;
/* Create the core table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sequences TEXT, classification TEXT, other_if_any TEXT DEFAULT 'ooops');
/* load the core table with some 300000 rows (after doing playing around) */
WITH 
    /* Create a CTE (temp table) with the core sequence indentifiers */
    /* note very little knowledge of DNA */
    sequences(seq) AS (
        SELECT 'A' UNION ALL SELECT 'B' UNION ALL SELECT 'C' UNION ALL SELECT 'G' UNION ALL SELECT 'T'
    ),
    /* create CTE with groups of indentifiers (which could potentially compress the stored sequences (intended just as a hint)) */
    /* i.e. all permutations (3125) of 5 identifiers */
    grouped_sequences_by_5 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        groupof5.seq ||s2.seq||s3.seq||s4.seq||s5.seq AS groupof5
    FROM sequences AS groupof5 
        JOIN sequences AS s2 
        JOIN sequences AS s3 
        JOIN sequences AS s4 
        JOIN sequences AS s5
    )
    ,
    /* Create another CTE of random rows (300000 rows) */
    ready_to_insert(sequences,classification) AS (
        SELECT 
            (SELECT groupof5 FROM grouped_sequences_by_5 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1 ),
            'CAT'||(abs(random()) % 10)
        UNION ALL SELECT 
            (SELECT groupof5 FROM grouped_sequences_by_5 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1 ),
            'CAT'||(abs(random()) % 10)
        FROM ready_to_insert LIMIT 300000
    )
INSERT INTO `table` (sequences,classification) SELECT * FROM ready_to_insert;
SELECT * FROM `table`;

/*----------------------------------------*/
/* Now demonstrate the pagination_control */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pagination_control (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,p_limit,p_offset);
/* initialise pagination table */
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO pagination_control VALUES(1,1000,0);
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY id LIMIT (SELECT p_limit FROM pagination_control) OFFSET (SELECT p_offset FROM pagination_control);
/* Always update after selection to ready for next block */
UPDATE pagination_control SET p_offset = p_offset + p_limit;
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY id LIMIT (SELECT p_limit FROM pagination_control) OFFSET (SELECT p_offset FROM pagination_control);
/* Always update after selection to ready for next block (again) */
UPDATE pagination_control SET p_offset = p_offset + p_limit;
/* optional to alter e.g. set blocks to 500 rows per block */
UPDATE pagination_control SET p_limit = 500;
/* and so on */
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY id LIMIT (SELECT p_limit FROM pagination_control) OFFSET (SELECT p_offset FROM pagination_control);
UPDATE pagination_control SET p_offset = p_offset + p_limit;
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY id LIMIT (SELECT p_limit FROM pagination_control) OFFSET (SELECT p_offset FROM pagination_control);
UPDATE pagination_control SET p_offset = p_offset + p_limit;
/* Cleanup the demo environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pagination_control;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`;
```

- so first some 300000 rows are inserted (obviously just to demonstrate the pagination_control)

  - you may wish to consider how grouping sequences could be used to reduce the overall data e.g. in the above every 5 bytes could be represented by 2 bytes (the id(rowid) of the `grouped_sequences_by_5` CTE IF it were a made permanent table).
  - e.g. Result 1 could be:-
  - [image]
  - ***Note*** the above apparently random selection of the group of 5 sequences isn't actually random throughout due to just the single value being calculated just the once. As the actual underlying data is just for demonstration this ***error in the demo*** has been left asis.

However, it is after the above that the pagination_control table is demonstrated itself.

First it is created with the two core columns (`p_limit` and `p_offset`), the id column just used to maintain the single row.

The following SELECT (Result 2) demonstrates how the pagination_control is used to determine the selected rows.

[image]

The following UPDATE, which should typically immediately follow the SELECT, shows how the pagination table can be prepared for the next SELECT (Result 3).

[image]

After this 2nd SELECT an UPDATE changes the LIMIT from 1000 to 500. The 3rd SELECT (Result 4) and the 4th SELECT (Result 5) then grab then next block of 500.

[image]

[image]

Of course you can easily manipulate the "pagination_control" table and have very flexible control e.g. to reset you could update it so that `p_limit` is 1000 and `p_offset` is 0 to rerun with 1000 blocking/paging factor.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two options:

1. update the `__getitem__` method of your `Dataset` to look up a single row from the table by index
2. use the [datasets](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/) library with the [sql interface](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/en/tabular_load#databases)